handle array in json using duck db
I have this json:
    {
     "age": 34,
     "names": ["david", "john"]
    }

And I want to create a parquet file using duck db query like this:
    select i ->> '$.age'      AS age,
           (i ->> '$.names')::JSON AS names,
    FROM ( SELECT UNNEST((info ->> '$.Data'):: JSON []) AS i, Id, DATE FROM my_json_report);

The names column is loaded into my snowflake db like this:
    [
      "[\"david\",\"john\"]"
    ]


What can I do in my duck db query in order to be as regular array?
I tried all this functions but none helped me:
    ARRAY(SELECT jsonb_array_elements_text((l -> '$.names')::jsonb)) AS names,

    json_extract_array(l, '$.names') AS names,

    json_extract(l, '$.names') AS names,

    regexp_split_to_array(trim(BOTH '[]' FROM json_extract(l, '$.names')::TEXT), ',') AS names.


Would you not need to cast to a list of strings instead of json? e.g. (i->'$.names')::varchar[]

Hi - why would you want to load data into Snowflake like that? What are you planning on doing with it once it's in Snowflake?

it is an easy way to process json. and snowflake is the relational db i'm working with
